# Set current displayed tab programmatically in p:wizard

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Is it possible to set current displayed tab *programmatically* in [`<p:wizard>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/wizard.xhtml)?

For example, I want that for two different request to the same page which contains a wizard, to have a different tab selected.

What I am currently trying to do, is to have a wizard with many tabs, in the second tab I have a redirection to another page, so when I come back I want to come to the last step which caused the redirection.

Can you please help me ? Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [primefaces documentation](http://primefaces.org/documentation.html) there's a `step` attribute for **`p:wizard`** tag, which specifies the step of the wizard you're currently in.

> **attribute:** step
>   **default value:** 0
>   **type:** String
>   **description:** Id of the current step in flow

You must bind this attribute to a value of your backing bean and maintain it during redirection and coming back. If your wizard's bean is `@ViewScoped` you'll loose that info during redirection step, so you have to pass it using a [view param](http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/07/learning-jsf2-page-params-and-page-actions/) or [flash scope](http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/07/learning-jsf2-using-flash-scope/).

Answer (score 5):

My answer would most probably not meet your complete requirements, but, nonetheless, it may point you towards solution to your problem.

As far as I know, the PrimeFaces Wizard UIComponent is designed for a workflow of *one* page. That effectively means that inputs will be handled by a backing beans that is in a view scope.

This way, making a redirection on a certain step will clear all data inputs, because your view changes and the old one is destroyed.

Anyway, a means of setting a current tab for display is step attribute of Wizard component. So,

```
<p:wizard step="#{wizardBean.currentStep}" >...</p:wizard>
```

will force the wizard to show you step which you specified in your bean. You may be able to get it by using, for example, a view parameter, like in

```
<f:viewParam name="step" value="#{wizardBean.currentStep}" />
```

But it will make sense if lifetime of your bean is more that for a view, for example, the bean could be put in session scope.

That said, maybe it is a better idea to do login beforehand. Or, if it is absolutely necessary to do it in step 2 of your wizard, provide for a built-in login functionality in a page itself, or in a popular window?

Also, programmatically the setting you speak of can be achieved via a binding of component to your backing bean and setting the step value in the backing bean, for example, in a preRenderView event.