# p:wizard and message components with autoUpdate set to true

Tags: jsf, primefaces, wizard

A `<p:wizard>` needs to display a message on `<p:messages>` and/or `<p:growl>` after it performs the last step before forwarding back to the first step as follows (The wizard performs three steps).

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:messages id="message" for="message" redisplay="false" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"/>

    <p:wizard widgetVar="wizard">
        <p:tab title="Tab 1"></p:tab>
        <p:tab title="Tab 2"></p:tab>

        <p:tab title="Tab 3">
            <p:commandButton process="@this"
                             oncomplete="alert('Message'); PF('wizard').loadStep(PF('wizard').cfg.steps[0], true)"
                             value="Submit"
                             actionListener="#{bean.action}"/>
        </p:tab>
    </p:wizard>
</h:form>
```

The managed bean :

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Bean() {}

    public void action() {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage();
        message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
        message.setSummary("Message Summary");
        message.setDetail("Message from backing bean");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("message", message);
    }
}
```

The `FacesMessage` set to `message` in the `action()` method in the bean appears for a very short while and disappears all of a sudden like a flick (In the current example, I gave it a pause by adding an alert box in between).

The culprit is the JavaScript code in the `oncomplete` handler of the `<p:commandButton>`.

```
PF('wizard').loadStep(PF('wizard').cfg.steps[0], true)
```

This forwards the wizard back to the first step from the last step causing the auto updated `<p:messages>` component to disappear.

Ignoring auto update (i.e. setting it to `false`) is not an option in the real project nor setting `ignoreAutoUpdate` to `true` helps in the case as the `<p:commandButton>` itself is not responsible for performing this task.

How to prevent that code from updating the `<p:messages>` component so that it displays the said message/s consistently?

---

It should genuinely be noted that in real situation, `<p:messages>` is placed on the master template in the very beginning of `<h:body>` with the intention of displaying some global messages corresponding to some exceptions being thrown from the service layer like `javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException`. Therefore, applying some condition(s) on `<p:messages>` would affect that component globally - something needs to be done being independent of `<p:messages>`.

Comment: Can you you elaborate on this _" nor setting ignoreAutoUpdate to true helps in the case as the `<p:commandButton>` itself is not responsible for performing this task."_

Comment: I am also a bit surprised as to why that piece of code clears out auto updated messages even though `ignoreAutoUpdate` of `<p:commandButton>` is set to `true`.

Comment: Maybe your PF version does not support ignoreAutoUpdate

Comment: It is PrimeFaces 5.2. It does support that attribute. It works at other places. There was also a [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31806013/1391249) previously.

Comment: There is a difference with the duplicate. I think it is the loadStep that is doing an additional ajax call. Try setting it IN the action() method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15039898/primefaces-wizard-set-current-displayed-tab-programatically

Comment: `step` seems to have been meant only for an initial step value with which the wizard step is to be shown, when it is first loaded. The wizard has no effect, when another value for `step` is dynamically set. I tried to update/process the whole form also tried with `ajax="false"` after performing the last step. The wizard always stays on the last step no matter what `step` value is set in the corresponding managed bean property. BTW, `PF('wizard').loadStep()` sends an additional AJAX request  which is shown by the traffic monitor but `ignoreAutoUpdate` should take care of it.

Comment: _"BTW, PF('wizard').loadStep() sends an additional AJAX request which is shown by the traffic monitor but ignoreAutoUpdate should take care of it."_ Wrong assumption (well, imo). It is not an an ajax call made by the commandbutton 'logic' itself (as you stated yourself in your Q). It is an ajax call that is done by the ajax framework in the oncomplete. So it is not by default part of some 'ignoreAutoUpdate' wrapper logic. Maybe PF could enhance the ignoreAutoUpdate logic in a way that does what you expect. And did you try using onscuccess instead of oncomplete? Does that make a difference?

Comment: `onsuccess` has the same effect as `oncomplete` in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on PF source code, effect of `ignoreAutoUpdate="true"` could be achieved by supplying `primefaces.ignoreautoupdate=true` request parameter to the ajax postback. However, I'm not seeing a trivial way to pass that to the `loadStep()` function without hacking the JS source code.

I can think of a workaround to set some boolean in the JS scope, and check for it during the `pfAjaxSend` DOM event and then append the desired request parameter to the ajax request query string as available by `options.data`. To prevent global JS scope pollution, I opted to add a custom property to the global `PrimeFaces` object.

```
<p:commandButton ... oncomplete="PrimeFaces.ignoreAutoUpdate=true; PF('wizard').loadStep(PF('wizard').cfg.steps[0], true)" />
```

```
$(document).on("pfAjaxSend", function(event, xhr, options) {
    if (PrimeFaces.ignoreAutoUpdate) {
        options.data += "&primefaces.ignoreautoupdate=true";
        PrimeFaces.ignoreAutoUpdate = false;
    }
});
```

It's this way also reusable elsewhere by simply setting `PrimeFaces.ignoreAutoUpdate=true` in JS before the ajax postback.

This approach might be worth an enhancement request to the PF guys.

Comment: How do you debug and come to know that this particular thing in the source code is the root cause of any given problem?