# How to restore current step in Primefaces wizard after page refresh?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have created a primefaces wizard like this:

```
    <p:wizard id="my-wizard" showNavBar="false" flowListener="#{myBean.onFlowProcess}" 
            widgetVar="transactionWizard">

              <p:tab id="first" titleStyleClass="hidden-wizard-title">
              </p:tab>
              <p:tab id="second" titleStyleClass="hidden-wizard-title">
              </p:tab>
</p:wizard>
```

Below is onflowProcess() code in my bean class. (My bean class has view access scope)

```
  public String onFlowProcess( FlowEvent event ){
        return event.getNewStep();
    }
```

My problem is that, when I am on second tab page and refresh the page, it moves back to first tab page after refreshing. Bit I want page to be stayed at current tab after refresh. How do we do that?

Comment: Taking the same course as this guy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717867/primefaces-wizard-on-page-refresh-stay-on-current-step

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set current displayed tab programmatically in p:wizard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15039898/set-current-displayed-tab-programmatically-in-pwizard)

Comment: I have checked the answer there. its not working.

Comment: 'Not working' is what an end-user would describe. I assume you are a developer, so investigate more. Is the value set at all in the bean? Is the beanscope correct to survive a page request (new GET, so viewscoped is to short and you either need sessionscoped, a custom viewaccessscoped or pass the 'step' as a parameter to the refresh! As all stated in the duplicate!